# Car making a screeching/squealing noise when reversing and turning at the same time slowly (whether I'm braking, or not)

Tags: noise

I'm noticing my venza is making a gentle metal screeching sound when I am reversing and turning at the same time very slowly. I don't hear the sound when driving on the road in normal speed, only when coming out of parking in reverse.. sounds like the sound is coming from the back of the car..

The noise is ocurring only when I am reversing and turning my steering wheel to the right..

What could it be?